# Javascript: Update price when quantity changes

Tags: javascript, html, price, calculation

I am new to javascript and I have been working on this for 4 days now and I haven't made any progress. I have tried a bunch of different options. I saw an example like mine that worked...but it isn't working for me. :( I am trying to have the price adjust as the quantity of tickets changes. Below is the javascript and below that is the html. Any assistance is much appreciated! Thank you!

```
document.getElementById("totalTicketCost").value = 0 + "." + 00;

function ticketCost()


{

var ticketCost = 5.5;

var inputTicketQuantity = document.getElementById("inputTicketQuantity").value;

var totalTicketCost = parseFloat(ticketCost) * inputTicketQuantity;



if (!isNaN(totalTicketCost))





document.getElementById("totalTicketCost").innerHTML = totalTicketCost;



}
```

```
    <form onsubmit="" ="return alertDetails()" id="formPurchaseTickets" enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="mailto:cmst388@xyz.com">
        <h1>Ticket Purchasing Form</h1>
        <p class="alert">Act fast! This transaction must be completed in <span id="timer"></span> minutes.</p>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="required">How many tickets would you like to purchase?</label>
            <input id="inputTicketQuantity" tabindex="1" required type="number" value="0" name="ticket-quantity" min="1" max="3" step="1" title="You can only buy between 1 and 3 tickets">
            $<span id="totalTicketCost">0.00</span>
        </div>

        <div id="contactInfo" style="display:none;">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="required">Name:</label>
                <input required name="name" tabindex="2" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" title="Enter only letters. e.g. Smith">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="required">E-mail:</label>
                <input id="inputEmail" tabindex="3" required name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter e-mail address"  onblur="validateEmail()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <input type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Purchase Tickets"> <input type="reset">
    </form>



    <script src="event_registration.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? You don't seem to be calling the `ticketCost()` function...

Comment: Yes. I have tried "onchange="totalTicketCost"", and "onclick". I guess I'm confused where to put the trigger. The teacher said not to edit the html file, which I assume means I can start the function in javascript? However, that doesn't make sense to me because it's when the number of tickets changes that the monetary value changes. For example, I enter quantity of tickets as "2" and then the price updates to $11. If I put 3 tickets, it's  $16.50.

Comment: You can attach listener in JavaScript as well, without changing html code, see my answer

Comment: Okay. I am packing up my laptop and headed home. I'll give that a try when I get home. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I marked the correct answer. I still have a lot to learn. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with only ES5 here (assuming you're not transpiling at this stage), I did a quick refactor.

```
var ticketInput = document.getElementById("totalTicketCost");
var inputTicketQuantity = document.getElementById("inputTicketQuantity");
var ticketCost = 5.5;

// Handle the precision up to >= $100
function changeCost( num ) {
  var cost = new Number( parseFloat( num ) * ticketCost );
  var precision = cost.toString().length === 3 ? 3 : 4;
  return cost.toPrecision( precision );
}

inputTicketQuantity.addEventListener('input', function( event ) {
  var value = event.target.value;
  if ( !isNaN( value ) ) {
    ticketInput.innerHTML = changeCost( value );
  }
});
```

You definitely want to separate out the JS from the HTML as much as possible, avoid the hard to read inline stuff like `<form onsubmit="" ="return alertDetails()"`, should at least be `<form onsubmit="return alertDetails()"` to fix it.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! This solves the problem. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: No problem at all. You'll have some even better tools to use when you get to ES6 / ES2015. : )

Comment: FYI on my own response that I'm noticing - `var cost = Number()` not `var cost = new Number()`

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to you quantity field, and recalculate price.

```
document.querySelector("#inputTicketQuantity").addEventListener("input", function() {
  let count = this.value;
  calculatePrice(count);
});
```

Comment: Only use `let` when you want to warn readers of your code that you're going to reassign the variable. Otherwise, always use `const`.

Comment: let question author desides by yourself how to do better in his cace

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function `ticketCost()` on value change event of input quantity textbox

```
<input id="inputTicketQuantity" onkeydown="ticketCost()" tabindex="1" required type="number" value="0" name="ticket-quantity" min="1" max="3" step="1" title="You can only buy between 1 and 3 tickets">
```

Or you can add listener in JavaScript as

```
document.getElementById("inputTicketQuantity").addEventListener("onkeydown", ticketCost);
```

Add it outside your JavaScript function ticketCost()

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific on what you're trying to achieve, but here is functionality to update your total cost as the user adds tickets -

In JS:

```
function updateCost(count)
{
   var ticketCost = 5.5;
   document.getElementById("totalTicketCost").innerHTML = count * ticketCost;
}
```

In HTML

```
<input id="inputTicketQuantity" tabindex="1" required type="number" value="0" name="ticket-quantity" onchange="updateCost(this.value)" min="1" max="3" step="1" title="You can only buy between 1 and 3 tickets">
```